# UIButtons in XIB not responding to taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, xib

I am trying to add two buttons to a xib but neither button is responding to taps. I have gone through the similar questions on here about this but haven't found a working solution yet.

In the xib I have a background view -> a smaller view -> two side by side buttons divided by a sibling small view.

The buttons are the top most layer of the xib. I have enabled userInteraction & clip subviews on all super and sibling views.

I have a breakpoint set in the view's controller class which is getting hit when the view is init'd. I have simplified the class as much as possible but when I tab either button nothing is happening at all. This view sits on top of a tableview which is reacting as expected.

I pulled out the xib and controller files and added them to a sample app. It is exhibiting the same issues. I have attached the code for that sample app at the bottom of this post.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP1tI.png)

Here is the code I am using to init add the xib to my rootVC:

```
PageSwitchViewController *pageSwitchViewController = [PageSwitchViewController new];
[pageSwitchViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - [pageControlHeight integerValue]), [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [pageControlHeight integerValue])];
[self.view addSubview:pageSwitchViewController.view];
```

Comment: Usually nib files are tied to file owners, try to add the action from UIControlEventTouchUpInside to the file owner rather than to the viewController scene.

Comment: Maybe this is just a symptom of another issue then? The nib's file owner is the same controller as where I am placing the IBActions.

Comment: tap the view debugger button in xcode and see if the view inside which the button is, that frame should be larger than button and check also if the some other view is not coming infront of button

Comment: buttons are def on the top. i do that explicitly in code and in the view debugger have confirmed that. the buttons do go slightly out of the bounds of their super view but only because of the rounded corners. i did try to shrink the buttons down to a much smaller size that are within the super view but same problem, they aren't reacting to taps.

Comment: Share your code so its easy to find problem

Comment: The buttons are in front for sure as it can be seen from their ordering in interface builder list. But why are you declaring your methods inside private interface? I see no use for that, they do not need to be declared there. Try to eliminate those.

Comment: I deleted the private connects and made a new connection to one of the buttons in the implementation, still no go. 

I do want the xib to be connected to a VC and not just a UIView class right? If so I am using a pretty default init method but looking around online I see some people are using initWithNibName and presenting differently. What is the right way to alloc/init and present a xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
[self.view addSubview:pageSwitchViewController.view];
```

Because I am adding the view I am not storing the rest of the controller in memory. I added a private property for the controller to my the parent controller's class and now the buttons are working as expected.